# Minimum burden resistor for current transformer

Tags: resistors, current-transformer

In calculating a burden resistor for a current transformer, what determines how low a value you can use?

Assuming you can still obtain the minimum voltage acceptable to the ADC, what other factors determine the lowest acceptable burden value?

I have a circuit where I have some margin at the minimum current end but I want to reduce the voltage at the maximum current end of the calculation. I can achieve this by lowering the burden value but I am not sure how low I should go.

This particular current transformer datasheet uses the minimalist approach and does not specify any burden values or DC resistance values.

Comment: A CT would be happy to see a short circuit on the secondary. Lowest practical value depends on how sensitive your I=V/R voltage measurement is.

Comment: Linearity goes awry for too high a BR value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum value is 0Ω, shorted if you will. Obviously the output voltage is also zero. 
The maximum value is limited as this may cause voltage to rise to excessive levels.

1) where can we find the datasheeet?
2) what are the voltage levels you wish to see at the secondary side of the transformer? 
3) What is the current range for the primary?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Very helpful. The datasheet is here: http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/sites/default/files/SCT013-000_datasheet.pdf  I am looking for 120uV to 720mV

Comment: Any additional information should be added to your original question, not in comments. Edit your original question and put the details there - people aren't keen to comb pages of comments to get the details they need to help you out.

Comment: The datasheet seems to contradict itself. It says that

Comment: The datasheet seems to contradict itself. It specifies a transformer ratio of 50mV/100A = 500μV/A (Current to voltage transformer) but then the schematic drawing shows a pure current transformer. 
You have to clarify this with the manufacturer. If it is indeed a current to voltage transformer there's no way to get a 720mV output unless you make use of an amplifier eg, opmamp.
If it is a pure current transformer with a turns ratio of 100/0.05 you get 720mV when loaded with a 14.4Ω precision resistor.

Comment: If fidelity of the secondary signal is of importance to you, you should consider a resistor as low as possible. Currents in power lines are no longer sinusoidal and a higher load resistance may cause more linear distortion.

Comment: I noted the anomaly regarding having volts out.  I think it is a typo. The same range of CTs have other models with burden resistors fitted, so they do have volts out.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is to select the resistor for your minimum current level requirement that produces level of voltage needed to satisfy subsequent amplifier and A/D converter. If this value resistor then produces too high of voltage at the high end of your current range that it would swamp out your amplifier or A/D converter you can adopt the idea of dynamic range switching. One simple way to do this is to put a voltage divider across the burden resistor and feed the divided voltage to the down wind circuit.

You could even use multiple voltage dividers for different ranges. The various voltages would get fed to the amplifier & A/D converter via an analogue mux. The range selection could be done from output pins of your MCU. Alternatively you could build an auto range selector by adding some comparators that monitored the burden resistor voltage and select the appropriate divider accordingly. In this case the comparator outputs would be inputs to the MCU so it knows what range it is measuring on.

As a general guideline make the sum of the voltage divider resistors be at least 10x the burden resistor value. Then make sure that the amplifier - A/D circuit input impedance is at least 10x higher than the voltage divider impedance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  In this case it has to be one continuous range.